# What web sites are there that gives you the "Developer" the ability to block clients from changing html?

Tags: html, css, client-side

I use to know what it was called but it was years ago. The site basically allowed the developer to add an ID or Class inside tags to let the site know the client is only able to make changes to the code between tags with a certain ID or Class. I hope someone knows. This is killing me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of anywebsite that ever allowed that functionality without using a Content Management System (CMS).  Are you perhaps remembering a particular CMS system?

Or is it a WIKI you are after?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're thinking of [CushyCMS](http://www.cushycms.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you're thinking of Adobe's Dreamweaver and [Contribute](http://www.adobe.com/products/contribute/)  (formerly Macromedia).